# surjectivity of a function

Tags: analysis

Let $g\in C([0,1])$ be a positive function (this means: $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. ) $\phi_g:C([0,1])\to C([0,1]),\; f\mapsto gf$ and $C([0,1])=\{f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}; \text{f is continuous}\}$. Is $\phi$ surjective? Let $h\in C([0,1])$, i must find a $f\in C([0,1])$ satisfying $\phi(f)=h$. In other words for $h\in C([0,1])$ there exits a function $f\in C([0,1])$ such that $gf=h$. Im not sure if it is satisfied. I can imagine that not every h has the function g of one of it's factors. Maybe if g=exponentialfunction and $h(x)=x^2$, h lies not in the image of $\phi_{e^x}$ I would say. Are my thoughts correct? Or is the map always surjective? Maybe it is only the case if g=id.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $\phi_g$ were surjective, then in particular, there is some $f\in C([0,1])$ such that $gf=1$, where $1$ is the constant $1$ function.

- Can you think of a function $g$ for which $\phi_g$ is not surjective?
- Describe a necessary condition on the function $g$ for there to be some $f\in C([0,1])$ with $gf=1$.
- Suppose such an $f$ exists for $g$.  If $h\in C([0,1])$, does there exist some $k$ such that $gk=h$?

Comment: a necessary condition for g to be some f as above with gf=1 is surjectivity of g I would say. for example $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C},\; x\mapsto x$ is not surjective. But if I take $f(x)=1$ for every $x\in [0,1]$ I obtain the constant 1-function $[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @user225385 One thing you could clarify - when you say $gf$, do you mean $g\circ f$ (composition) or $g\times f$ (pointwise multiplication)?